# javascript: Unchecking all checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have problem dealing with unchecking all checkboxes. When I click on a toggle all checkbox, it could check all checkboxes. But if I uncheck the toggle all checkbox, nothing happens. All checkboxes are not unchecked. Below is my coding in javascript:

```
<script>
var isAllCheck = false;
function togglecheckboxes(cn){

    var cbarray = document.getElementsByName(cn);
    for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){

        if( isAllCheck == false ){
            cbarray[i].checked = "true";
            //alert( "it is false" );
        }else{ 
            cbarray[i].removeAttribute("checked");
            //alert( "it is true" );
        }
}   
isAllCheck = !isAllCheck;   
}
</script>
```

I had even tried this coding, but still failed:

```
<script>
var isAllCheck = false;
function togglecheckboxes(cn){

    var cbarray = document.getElementsByName(cn);
    for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){

        if( isAllCheck == false ){
            cbarray[i].checked = "true";
            //alert( "it is false" );
        }else{ 
            cbarray[i].checked = "false";
            //alert( "it is true" );
        }
}   
isAllCheck = !isAllCheck;   
}
</script>
```

Below is my PHP coding for your reference:

```
echo "\t<div class='item'>
<span class='CDTitle'>{$cd['CDTitle']}</span>
<span class='CDYear'>{$cd['CDYear']}</span>
<span class='catDesc'>{$cd['catDesc']}</span>
<span class='CDPrice'>{$cd['CDPrice']}</span>
<span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='cd[]' value='{$cd['CDID']}' title='{$cd['CDPrice']}' /></span>
</div>\n";
```

Any tips on resolving this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is. :-)

Comment: @isherwood I had reedited my post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem boils down to how you're setting the `checked` property of the checkox. You're assigning a string with "true" where you should be assigning the boolean value `true`.

So to fix your code is easy:

```
if( isAllCheck == false ){
    cbarray[i].checked = true;
}else{ 
    cbarray[i].checked = false;
}
```

or, more succinctly

```
cbarray[i].checked = !isAllCheck
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/SEJZP/

Answer (score 15):

**Update**

As per comments, `Array.from` is not necessary anymore on modern browsers, so you could do

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(el => el.checked = isAllCheck);
```

**Original answer**

After validating that `isAllCheck` is correct with your UI logic, you may do both with a simple vanilla-js one-liner

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')).forEach(el => el.checked = isAllCheck);
```

Comment: Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')).forEach(el => el.checked = isAllCheck);

Comment: You don't need `Array.from` to use `forEach` on the result of `querySelectorAll` in modern browsers.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function uncheckElements()
{
 var uncheck=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 for(var i=0;i<uncheck.length;i++)
 {
  if(uncheck[i].type=='checkbox')
  {
   uncheck[i].checked=false;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The code snippet doesn't run.

Answer (score 2):

You could also make it a Boolean Variable.

```
<script>
var isAllCheck = new Boolean(false);
function togglecheckboxes(cn){

var cbarray = document.getElementsByName(cn);
for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){

    if(isAllCheck){ //and then you could make this shorter.
        cbarray[i].checked = true;
        //alert( "it is false" );
    }else{ 
        cbarray[i].removeAttribute("checked");
        //alert( "it is true" );
    }
}   
isAllCheck = !isAllCheck;   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <script>
var isAllCheck = false;
function togglecheckboxes(master,cn){

    var cbarray = document.getElementsByName(cn);
    for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){

        if( isAllCheck == false ){
            cbarray[i].checked = true;
            //alert( "it is false" );
        }else{ 
            cbarray[i].checked = false;
            //alert( "it is true" );
        }
}   
isAllCheck = !isAllCheck;   
}
</script>
```

Comment: @iBlue Thanks for reply. I had tried your code too, but still can't.